How to fix this while I am testing I am getting error message in this flow
The API sharepointonline returned an invalid response for workflow operation Get_items of type OpenApiConnection.
Error:

The API operation 'GetItems' is missing required property 'body/value/23/Description_x0020_of_x0020_Probl'.

How to fix this since fields are already present in the share point page.

https://powerplatformtrainings.com/2021/07/07/resolve-the-api-sharepointonline-returned-an-invalid-response-for-workflow-operation-get_items-of-type-openapiconnection-error-details-the-api-operation-getitems-is-missing-requi/
